# Xamarin Studio Error: A valid Xcode installation could not be found

Tags: xcode, xamarin

I updated Xcode this morning (version 4.6.2) and right now, I cannot compile my projects.

> Error: A valid Xcode installation could not be found. If your copy of
>   Xcode is installed to a non-standard prefix, please specify the
>   location in Xamarin Studio's Preferences under 'SDK Locations'

I checked that SDK Locations are good but still same problem.

Any ideas to solve this problem ? Xamarin Studio 4.0.3 (Build 13)

Comment: A new version of xamarin has been released to fixed this

Comment: Where can this version be found please?

Comment: @duDE Its coming up now in Check for Updates in Xamarin Studio.

Comment: update works for Xamarin but not for MonoDevelop

Comment: Check for Updates utterly failed for me, but I just went to xamarin.com, jumped through hoops, and downloaded and ran the full installer again.  This got me Xamarin Studio 4.0.5, which appears to solve the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, it seems to be the Bug of Xcode 4.6.2: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/10620/#Comment_10620

> There is a known issue with Xcode 4.6.2, we would recommend that you
>   re-download Xcode 4.6.1 and continue using that until we get a fix out
>   for Xamarin Studio. You can re-download Xcode 4.6.1 from
>   https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

The only one way is to go back to 4.6.1 :(

Comment: Where can we download 4.6.1? I can't find that version anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 5):

Xamarin Studio 4.0.4 released, fixes incompatibility with Xcode 4.6.2

Comment: Where can this version be found please?

Comment: In your Xamarin Studio or MonoDevelop app, search for updates from your app menu

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Is a bug and you need download 4.6.1 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads

You just need to be registered as Apple developer and will find previous version on Developer Tools

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to have a paid developeraccount to get the 4.6.1 version of xcode from apple?
I only have the free account and I haven't found it on the apple hp.

Edit:
A Screenshot from my downloadssection on the apple hp:[image: No Xcode 4.6.1!!]

Comment: If I go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads the "newest" xcode I found was 3.2 on page 4, released Aug 31, 2009

Comment: And if I go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action, I see on the page one the Xcode 4.6.1. You can try to get it from here as well:  chip.de/downloads/Xcode_52267808.html

Comment: Maybe it's country specific, because also the chip hp links to apple. I am in Austria